# Matplotlib graph does not show in Python Interactive Window

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, python-interactive

The following is my code, but I can't get the plot to show on my Visual Studio Code even though I am running this on the Python Interactive Window, which should usually show a graph plot after running. The tables are showing just fine. I also do not get a default graph which pops up like it normally should. What am I doing wrong?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import talib

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df = df.sort_index()
macd, macdsignal, macdhist = talib.MACD(df['Close'], fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
macd = macd.to_list()
macdsignal = macdsignal.to_list()
macdhist = macdhist.to_list()

df['macd'], df['macdsignal'], df['macdhist'] = macd,macdsignal,macdhist  

ax = plt.gca()
print(df.columns)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='macd', color='blue',ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='macdsignal', color='red', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

The csv file has data that looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with matplotlib.use('agg'), which does not support the show() function. This prevented the graph from being displayed on Visual Studio's Interactive Window. The matplotlib.use('agg') method can, however, be used for saving your graph in a .png format.

According to Matplotlib.org, agg is "the canonical renderer for user interfaces, which uses the Anti-Grain Geometry C++ library to make a raster (pixel) image of the figure". More information can be found at this link [here](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)